# refactor angular javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this bit of javascript in an angular controller which works fine.

```
product.prod_custom_mb_qty = 0;
product.prod_custom_mb = null;
product.prod_custom_autoship = function (prod_name, prod_qty) {
  if (prod_name === "mb") {
    if (prod_qty === 0) {
      product.prod_custom_mb_qty = 0;
    } else {
      product.prod_custom_mb_qty += prod_qty;
    }
  }
  if (product.prod_custom_mb_qty < 1){
    product.prod_custom_mb_qty = 0;
    product.prod_custom_mb = null;
  } else if (product.prod_custom_mb_qty === 1) {
    product.prod_custom_mb = product.prod_custom_mb_qty + " Mango Bottle";
  } else if (product.prod_custom_mb_qty > 1) {
    product.prod_custom_mb = product.prod_custom_mb_qty + " Mango Bottles";
  }
  product.prod_custom_total = (product.prod_custom_mb_qty * 35);
}
```

The problem is I need to do it 8 more times for 8 different products and that would get a bit messy.
Is there a way I can refactor this so everything can be done more simply?

I thought I could do it by changing the names to the var to something like:

```
product.prod_custom_qty[prod_name]
product.prod_custom[prod_name]
```

But I can't seem to get that to work? Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest organizing it like:

```
var products = [];
var productCount = 8;

while(productionCount--) {
    var newProduct = {
        prod_custom_mb_qty: 0,
        prod_custom_mb: null
    };
    pruducts.push(newProduct);
    processProduct(newProduct);
}

function processProduct (product) {
    // Update your product properties here.
}
```